# Infinite recursion while overriding DataMapper methods

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I'm trying to override the `all()` and `first()` methods in a DataMapper model I have, but there are some issues. My methods are being called, but (as became immediately obvious) they call themselves recursively and cause a SystemStackError.

```
class Model
  include DataMapper::Resource
  include OtherModule

  def self.all(options = {})
    do_something()
    self.all(options.merge!(:deleted => false))
  end

  def self.first(options = {})
    self.first(options.merge!(:deleted => false))
  end

  property :id,           Serial
  property :name,         Text
  ...
```

All these methods should do is call the `all` or `first` method with `:deleted => false` unless otherwise specified.

I tried

```
  def self.all(options = {})
    super.self.all(options.merge!(:deleted => false))
  end
```

and

```
  def self.all(options = {})
    do_something()
    super.all(options.merge!(:deleted => false))
  end
```

to no avail. Is there a way around this infinite recursion problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing super

```
def self.all(options={})
    do_something()
    super(options.merge!(:deleted => false))
 end
```